# Get VLOOKUP "lookup_value" to refer to a cell reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have this table in the top-left of my sheet:

[image]

I want to point `VLOOKUP` to cell `A2` above, so that it returns `2`. How can I achieve this? This doesn't work:

```
// this outputs 1, not 2.
=VLOOKUP(A2,A1:B3,2,FALSE)
```

I want to explicitly work with cell references, somehow, such that each `A` inside the first column are treated as unique & independent.

Comment: You seem to have a formula that says "find the value of A2 in A1:A3 then return the value in the corresponding cell in B1:B3. Why would you not just go straight to B2? I feel there is a bigger picture here you are not sharing which means we can't really see the full intent of what you are trying to do. I suspect something like =INDEX(B1:B3,2) might be the sort of thing you need, or maybe just an implicit intersection. How are you deriving the "A2" to use in the first place?

Comment: The table is my shop inventory; first column is product name (e.g. Kellogs) *which may not be unique*, and second column is product quantity. Separately, I'm compiling a list of product sales, so I wish to refer to the item/product/product name itself, which is why I need to refer to the first column in the VLOOKUP and I can't refer just to the second.

Comment: If your product names are not unique then there does not seem to be a way to expect a computer to lookup an item and return a unique result.

Comment: What if I create a function that takes A2 as an input, and then returns the number 2? I can then use that to lookup the corresponding row in the sheet?

Comment: I can't see how your formula can "know" that it wants to reference cell A2 but cannot "know" that the result will be in B2. If you really want to you could use ROW(A2) and plug that into an INDEX function eg INDEX(B1:B3,ROW(A2))

Answer (score 0):

Because A appears multiple times, VLOOKUP will only return the first occurrence.

You need to add a unique identifier in order for it to work.

Comment: I want a way that doesn't involve making a unique ID.

What about a function that strips out the row number from the A2 reference, and using that row number?